# how can I get the answer in a list in python

Tags: python, recursion

I was asked to find y[1:5]**4 for y are 5 random numbers in range(0,20)

Here is my code

```
import numpy 
import random
y=random.sample([i for i in range(20)],5)
ans=np.zeros(10)
sum=0
for n in range(0,5):
ans[n]=sum+(y**4)
print(ans)
```

It shows type error:unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'list' and 'int'.
The answer should be a list of (y**4),how can I get the answer in a list
and can I do it using the method of recursive function?
Thankyou!

Comment: As an aside, `[i for i in range(20)]` should just be `list(range(20))`, but actually here, you can just use `range(20)` without converting it to a list

Comment: If you want to take every element in your list ```y``` to the 4th power, just use: ```np.power(y, 4)```